# Excel 2007 Function, last three items

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

My question is twofold, so bear with the wall of text. I'm making sort of a banking spreadsheet. I will input income/expenses in four columns (Date/Amount/Type/Description) and I need it to keep track of my day to day spending. I already have it so that if the date is not today, it won't add/subtract it until it is. Also, I have it so two/three/four weeks in the future. However, I want to add something to the effect of "Last three paychecks". The "Type" column has only three possible entries, "Income", "Transfer", and "Expense". If I can find a function to work for one, I'm sure I can get it to work with the rest easily. I need it to show the most recent "income" amount. For instance:

> Date    Amount      Type
>
> Sep 1    100         Income
>
> Sep 2    100         Expense
>
> Sep 3    100         Income
>
> Sep 4    100         Expense
>
> Sep 5    100         Income
>
> Sep 6    100         Income
>
> Sep 7    100         Income

Let's say it's Sep 6th today. I would want it to show Sep 5ths amount, Sep 5ths, and Sep 3rds. I don't want it to show expenses, and it's not yet Sep 7th. It would have to be three functions (one for each box), so how would I get it to do the most recent, second to most recent, and so on? If I can get it to work, I can edit to get the description as well, and refit it to expenses if need be.

Question 2:

I would like an "annual checkup" kind of thing. How would I get it to lookup each of every type (same as above), but then have cutoff dates so it's only one year?

Comment: Do you want to filter the data table too? Or do you just need the subtotal for the most recent entries?

Comment: Not even the subtotal, I want it to show the latest income entry in one cell, the next latest in another, and the next latest in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you get the three most recent transactions per type. It helps if you've used named ranges for your data sheet.

To get the 3 most recent Income dates, you can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(dates,LARGE(ROW(dates)*(dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),XXX)-1,1)
```

Where:

**dates** -- the cell range/column range that contains the dates
**types** -- the cell range/column that contains either "Income", "Transfer" or "Expenses"
**XXX** -- contains either 1 (most recent), 2 (2nd most recent) or 3.

To get the most recent amount and description, replace the first instance of `dates` in the formula above with the cell range that contains the money amounts and descriptions.

```
=INDEX(amounts,LARGE(ROW(dates)*(dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),XXX)-1,1)
```

&

```
=INDEX(descriptions,LARGE(ROW(dates)*(dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),XXX)-1,1)
```

In the example below, **dates** refers to `A2:A100`, **amounts** refers to `B2:B100`, **types** refers to `C2:C100` and **descriptions** refers to `D2:D100`.

[image]

In order for the formulas to work, the data table needs to be sorted *according to date* (oldest to latest). Be sure to commit the formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This also assumes that there are unique dates for each type of transaction (i.e. no multiple Income entries for a single date).

---

If you don't want to have to sort the table by date, here's an array formula you can try:

```
=INDEX(dates,
 MATCH(SMALL(IF((dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),(TODAY()-dates),""),XXX),
             IF((dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),(TODAY()-dates),""),0),1)
```

Where:

**dates** -- the cell range/column range that contains the dates
**types** -- the cell range/column that contains either "Income", "Transfer" or "Expenses"
**XXX** -- contains either 1 (most recent), 2 (2nd most recent) or 3

Again, to get the most recent amounts and descriptions, replace the first instance of `dates` in the formula above with the cell range that contains the money amounts and descriptions. Something like this:

```
=INDEX(amounts,
 MATCH(SMALL(IF((dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),(TODAY()-dates),""),XXX),
             IF((dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),(TODAY()-dates),""),0),1)
```

and

```
=INDEX(descriptions,
 MATCH(SMALL(IF((dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),(TODAY()-dates),""),XXX),
             IF((dates<=TODAY())*(types="Income"),(TODAY()-dates),""),0),1)
```

Comment: Extremely well written and well explained answer! Another couple for you though. Is there a reason it requires doing the ctrl/shift/enter keys vs. every other formula? Also, is there a way to do A:A without including the title?

Comment: Thanks Duall! Yes, you can replace the names with exact cell references; in my example above, "dates" actually refers to "A2:A100". The named range just makes it easier to type the formulas in Excel.

Comment: Oh, array formulas need to be Ctrl+Shift+Entered in order to work. This page explains it better than I can: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx

Comment: I have encountered a problem with this. If I have three expenses on the same day, it will take the first expense of that day and repeat it three times. Other than that it works wonders.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that in the answer -- I based it on your example and assumed the dates were unique. I'll update my answer as soon as I get off work. :)

Comment: Ah woops! You totally did, I guess I missed it. Sorry about that! Looking forward to the revised answer. =)